# Cannot set value conforming to protocol to property with protocol type

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a fake authenticator for my unit tests that can manually set the user as logged in or logged out and bypass the API my code actually uses where I'd need a real accessToken to log the user in.

I've wrapped the Authentication API my app uses in to the following class:

**API Wrapper**

```
import OIDC

protocol Authenticator {
    func getValidAccessToken(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?, String?) -> Void)
}

struct OIDCAuthenticator: Authenticator {

    func getValidAccessToken(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?, String?) -> Void) {
        //API call
        OIDCHelper.getValidAccessToken { (error, accessToken) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler( error, accessToken)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create a Fake Authenticator using the same protocol for testing purposes

**Fake/Testing Authenticator**

```
import OIDC
import Foundation

///Mocks the user being logged in our logged out for Testing purposes
struct FakeAuthenticator: Authenticator {
    let error: OIDCError?
    let accessToken: String?

    func getValidAccessToken(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?, String?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(error, accessToken)
    }

    init(loggedIn: Bool) {
        if loggedIn {
            error = .tokenNotFoundInKeychainData
            accessToken = nil
        } else {
            error = nil
            accessToken = "abcdefg"
        }
    }
}
```

Settings the `OIDCAuthenticator` API Wrapper works fine when settings the authenticator in the `ViewController` subclass.

**TableViewController Implementation**

```
import UIKit
import OIDC

class SettingsPageTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    // MARK: - Outlets and variables

    var authenticator: Authenticator!
    private var isUserLoggedIn = false

    // MARK: - LifeCycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authenticator = OIDCAuthenticator()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        authenticator.getValidAccessToken { [weak self] (error, _) in
            self?.isUserLoggedIn = (error == nil)
            self?.setLogginStatus()
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to do the same thing with the `FakeAuthenticator` in my Unit tests I get the following error:
[image]

**SettingsViewController Test Class**

```
import XCTest
import UIKit
@testable import MyProject

class SettingsViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: SettingsPageTableViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        configureViewControllerForTesting()
    }

    private func configureViewControllerForTesting() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SettingsPage", bundle: nil)
        let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        viewController = navigationController.topViewController as! SettingsPageTableViewController
        _ = viewController.view
    }

    func testSignInButtonIsAvailableWhenUnauthenticated() {
        viewController.authenticator = FakeAuthenticator(loggedIn: false)
    }
}
```

The same things happens when I swap out `FakeAuthenticator` with `OIDCAuthenticator`. I've also attempted to cast the `FakeAuthenticator` to `Authenticator` but this merely alters the Error to `Cannot assign value of type 'Authenticator' to type 'Authenticator!'.`

Why am I getting this error and what is the best approach to fixing this?

Comment: Are you importing any files into your test target or just using @testable import MyProject? This issue sounds like the way you're setting up the test project more than the code itself.

Comment: @u84six I’ve ticked the unit tests as targets got both files but nothing beyond that and the import (which is for the viewController).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "got both files". If you're importing your entire project using @ testable, then you don't need to target the files. I've seen this problem because of this reason.

Comment: @u84six Sorry I meant, both the `OIDCAuthenticator` and `FakeAuthenticator`. I’ll try removing them as targets see whether that’s the cause.

Comment: @u84six Removing the `OIDCAuthenticator` and the `FakeAuthenticator` from the Test target fixed this. Feel free to put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks I'd have never thought of this as the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the files from your test target since you're already importing your whole project with @testable.

Comment: Wow, didn't see that coming. Thanks for the help